# rijndael encryption

Tags: string, encryption, character, delimited

does this encryption library use pipe characters?  I'm storing the key in an array with the corresponding UserID value, and delimiting them with a pipe character.  If the library generates keys with pipe characters, those keys will get mangled when I split the string later.

Comment: What encryption library and what programming/scripting language you are talking about?

Answer (score 4):

The key should be random, and so could contain pipe characters incidentally. You should represent it as hexadecimal or base-64 in your pipe-delimited string to avoid unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a *library* named Rijndael.  I know of a symmetric cipher named Rijndael (now AES), but the cipher encrypts stuff---it doesn't generate keys.

If you mean the cipher, your question doesn't apply.  If you mean a particular piece of code (i.e. a library), a link would be useful so we can all see which particular Rijndael-implementing library you're talking about.

That being said, you can always recode any data to, say, base64, or hex, or binary, or whatever you prefer, that doesn't have a pipe character.